# Customizing Django Form based on model from 2 different models

Tags: python, django

I have the following 3 models in django.

```
models.py
=============

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
    
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    architecture = models.NameField()
    
class customer_services(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='customer_service_entries')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='customer_service_entries')
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
```

I have the following forms:

```
forms.py
==============


class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model       = Customer
        fields      = ["name"]

class CustomerServiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model       = customer_services
        fields      = ["service", "start", "end"]

class ServiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model       = Service
        fields      = ["name", "architecture"]
```

I am trying to have a form that I can add services to customers, and the issue I am running into is that the form will display only the fields from the CustomerServiceForm. The problem I am running into is that in the services table, I can have multiple services with the same name, but different architectures, but I don't have a way of displaying that in the form. So let's say I have the following values in the Service table:

```
services table
==============
id      ||      name        ||      architecture
1       ||      Test        ||      32Bit
2       ||      Test        ||      64Bit
3       ||      AnotherTest ||      32Bit
4       ||      AnotherTest ||      64bit
5       ||      TestTwo     ||      32Bit
```

Essentially what i would like to do is be able to show in the form something like this

```
<select name="services" id="services">
  <option value="1">Test - 32Bit</option>
  <option value="2">Test - 64Bit</option>
  <option value="3">AnotherTest - 32Bit</option>
  <option value="4">AnotherTest - 64Bit</option>
  <option value="5">TestTwo - 32Bit</option>
</select>
```

How can I display the architecture in the select dropdown, I can't figure out a way to get it to display in the form since it's not part of that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then I would just add an additional field to your Services model that will combine the name and architecture fields and access that field in the form. The below will add a save method that will create the value for you every time you save a model instance of Service. Adding the `__str__` method below the model will tell django that when this model is referenced it should return that aspect of the model.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    architecture = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    name_architecture = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_architecture

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_architecture = f'{self.name} - {self.architecture}'
        super(Service, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For the form you just have to reference the service field from customer_services and you'll then get a dropdown list names and architecture combinations that have been created and will show both.

```
class CustomerServiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = customer_services
        fields = ["service"]
```

Should look something like this once you're finished depending on what Service names and architectures you created.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, appreciate it, so your saying don't separate the customer_services and services model, just make it as one model. But the problem if i do that, is how can i have a dropdown based on a model, that can be updated for new services?

Comment: Oh ok, apologies I think I misunderstood. Actually that makes it more simple if I understand correctly now - I've updated my answer. Please see if that helps.

Comment: yes that was it, thank you so much, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Just override the string representation with `__str__` magic method of your model, in this case `Service`:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.architecture}'
```